# Passing PyArrayObject to C function

Tags: c, numpy

I try to write a Numpy extension module. The problem is that I am not sure how to pass a pointer to a `PyArrayObject` correctly to a C function, which results in the following behavior. Consider the code below:

```
/* File: test_mod.c */

#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_8_API_VERSION
#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL __NP_ARRAY_API

#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include "test_utilities.h"


static PyObject *
test_mod(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {

    PyArrayObject* arr;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O")) {
        printf("Error while parsing objects");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* do some checks 
    ... */

    do_something(&arr);
    return Py_None;
}

/* Method table
... */

/* Module definition structure 
... */

/* Module init function
... */
```

I want to pass `arr` by reference to a C function. In the above snipped, `arr` is a poiter to a `PyArrayObject`, which is a C `struct`. Hence, I came up with the following definition:

```
/* File: test_utilities.c */

#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_8_API_VERSION
#define NO_IMPORT_ARRAY
#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL __NP_ARRAY_API

#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>


void
do_something(struct PyArrayObject **arr) {

    int d = PyArray_NDIM(*arr));
    npy_intp N = PyArray_SIZE(*arr);
    printf("%i, %li", d, N);

}
```

`PyArray_NDIM(PyArrayObject* arr)` and `PyArray_SIZE(PyArrayObject* arr)` are macros from the [numpy Array API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#array-structure-and-data-access).

After compiliation, the modul produces the expected output, however, anlongside some compiler warnings. Hence, I doubt that everything works fine here.

Warning for test_modul.c:

```
test_utilities.h:1:25: warning: declaration of 'struct PyArrayObject'
will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
void print_array(struct PyArrayObject **arr);
                        ^
test_modul.c:63:14: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 
'PyArrayObject **' (aka 'struct tagPyArrayObject **') to parameter of    
type 'struct PyArrayObject **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        do_something(&signal);
                    ^~~~~~~
test_utilities.h:1:41: note: passing argument to parameter 'arr' here
void print_array(struct PyArrayObject **arr);
```

Warning for test_utilities.c:

```
test_utilities.c:10:20: warning: declaration of 'struct PyArrayObject'   
will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
do_something(struct PyArrayObject **arr) {
                   ^
test_utilities.c:13:51: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 
'struct PyArrayObject *' to parameter of type 'const PyArrayObject *'   
(aka 'const struct tagPyArrayObject *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        printf("Array has: %i dimensions.", PyArray_NDIM(*arr));
                                                         ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-
packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1464:35: note: passing 
argument to parameter 'arr' here
PyArray_NDIM(const PyArrayObject *arr)
                                  ^
test_utilities.c:16:28: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 
'struct PyArrayObject *' to parameter of type 'PyArrayObject *' (aka  
'struct tagPyArrayObject *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        npy_intp N = PyArray_SIZE(*arr);
                                  ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:91:59: note: expanded 
from macro 'PyArray_SIZE' #define PyArray_SIZE(m) 
PyArray_MultiplyList(PyArray_DIMS(m), PyArray_NDIM(m))
                                                   ^
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-
packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1482:29: note: passing 
argument to parameter 'arr' here
PyArray_DIMS(PyArrayObject *arr)
                            ^
```

I am not (yet) that good in C, and that's probably why I do not see whats is going on here. `do_something` takes a pointer to a struct. Hence, dereferencing `arr` in do something should give me the original pointer to the PyArrayObject struct from `test_mod` function in `test_mod.c`. Is that a misconception and if so, why is the producing the expected results?

To wrap this up, how do I pass a `PyArrayObject` correctly to a C function, such that there are no warnings (concerning incompatible pointer types, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying the docs again, I found the answer to be very simple. One just has to pass the struct pointer, like

```
do_something(arr);
```

The function itsef should read

```
void do_something(PyArrayObject *arr)
{
    int d = PyArray_NDIM(arr));
    npy_intp N = PyArray_SIZE(arr);
    printf("%i, %li", d, N);
}
```

Additionally, one should not forget to increase the reference count of `Py_None` in cases the C function has no return value. Hence, the end of the C function should read

```
Py_INCREF(Py_None);
return Py_None;
```

One could also use the built-in macro `Py_RETURN_NONE`, which has the same meaning as the above two lines.